# how to use searchmailbox() to search emails by passing date in the criteria of this method?

Tags: yii2, imap

This is my function and in this line of code * $mailIds = $mailbox->searchMailBox(); * i'm facing problem .. i want to search latest email but if i write anything in this method i'm facing the syntax problem or the blank page. please anyone can help me in solving this problem?

```
public function actionCreate1()
    {
        $imapConnection = new ImapConnection();

        $imapConnection->imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
        $imapConnection->imapLogin = 'example@gmail.com';
        $imapConnection->imapPassword = 'password';
        $imapConnection->serverEncoding = 'encoding'; // utf-8 default.
        $imapConnection->attachmentsDir = '/';
        $imapConnection->decodeMimeStr = true;
        

        $mailbox = new Mailbox($imapConnection);
        $mailbox->readMailParts = false;
        $mailIds = $mailbox->searchMailBox();

        foreach($mailIds as $mailId)
        {
            // Returns Mail contents
            $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mailId);

            // Read mail parts (plain body, html body and attachments
            $mailObject = $mailbox->getMailParts($mail);

            // Array with IncomingMail objects
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($mailObject);

            // Returns mail attachements if any or else empty array
            $attachments = $mailObject->getAttachments();
            foreach($attachments as $attachment){
                echo ' Attachment:' . $attachment->name . PHP_EOL;

                // Delete attachment file
                unlink($attachment->filePath);
            }
        }}
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify this a bit. Some code you don't include, called searchMailbox(), has a problem that you only describe as "the syntax problem or the blank page". Well, yes. What syntax problem and what's the code?

Comment: Also, is that your real password?